# Fade in on Scroll Plain JavaScript No JQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a text fade in on scroll similar to this https://codepen.io/hollart13/post/fade-in-on-scroll.

```
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
$('.monster').fadeIn('slow');
});

$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);

        }

    }); 

});

});
```

However, I do not want to use JQuery. I want to accomplish this using plain JavaScript. Unfortunately, most of the examples online are JQuery based and there's very little with plain JavaScript.

This is what I've attempted so far to "translate" this JQuery into plain JS. It's not working. Could anyone point at where I went wrong?

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("target");

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
var bottomOfObject = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect().top + 
window.outerHeight;

var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : 
(document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || 
document.body).scrollTop;

var bottomOfWindow = scrollTop + window.innerHeight;

if(bottomOfWindow > bottomOfObject){
  $(this).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 1500);
}
}
console.log(bottomOfObject);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple vanilla JavaScript solution

```js
var header = document.querySelector("#header");

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50) {
    header.className = "active";
  } else {
    header.className = "";
  }
};
```

```css
#header {
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: fixed;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#header.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Essentially there is an element positioned on the top of the screen which is invisible at first (with opacity 0) and using javascript I add an class to it that makes it visible (opacity 1) what makes it slowly visible instead of instantly is the transition: all 1s;

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version with dynamic opacity based on scroll position, I hope it helps
[Window Vanilla Scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/gugalondon/bqgbuv8z/1/)

```
function scrollHandler( event ) { 

        var margin = 100;
        var currentTop = document.body.scrollTop;
        var header = document.querySelector(".header");
        var headerHeight = header.getBoundingClientRect().height;
        var pct = (currentTop - margin) / ( margin + headerHeight );
        header.style.opacity = pct;
        if( pct > 1) return false;
    }

    function addListeners() { 
        window.addEventListener('scroll' , scrollHandler );
        document.getElementById("click" , function() { 
            window.scrollTop = 0;
        });
    }
    addListeners();
```